# new Date() - angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I used the following code to add one year from input date:

```
this.maxDate = this.drop.startDate;
this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 365);
```

In this context, `drop.startDate` is the input variable. But when I run this code, 1 year will be added to the maxDate variable, and drop.startDate value will changed to maxDate value. Look at the images. Any guidelines guys?

Before run the code

[image: Before run the code]

After run the code

[image: After run the code]

Comment: This is because you assigned a reference of this.drop.startDate to maxDate. So both of them will be updated at the same time.

Comment: And it is not the question but I recommand you to use date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1) in order to increment years in a JS date.

Comment: Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to 'clone' the date object. Otherwise the `startDate` will have the same reference as `maxDate`

```
this.maxDate = new Date(this.drop.startDate.getTime());
```